# Wrong year in javascript date

Tags: javascript, date

I need to subtract 365 days from the current date. I am not sure what is wrong in my date, it prints wierd year "5/17/111" instead of   5/17/2011. Can someone suggest me where I went wrong

```
currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate() - 365);
        var minDay = currentTime.getDate();
        var minMonth = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
        var minYear = currentTime.getYear();

    minDate = minMonth + '/' + minDay + '/' + minYear;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `getFullYear()` instead of `getYear()`

```
var minYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var minDay = currentTime.getDate();
var minMonth = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var minYear = currentTime.getFullYear() - 1;

minDate = minMonth + '/' + minDay + '/' + minYear;
```

Comment: But what if you calculate this in a leap year on February, 30? The result will be impossible. Edit: Wait - this also applies for the user's original code and December as the month.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be using getFullYear instead of getYear

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) would be helpful in this case.

```
moment().subtract('days', 365).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use getFullYear() instead of getYear().

You can read getYear() description here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6408-10/date.htm#1194138